# How to find which version of ruby is rhohub using?

Tags: response, rack, rhodes

I am hosting a *rhoconnect* app in my *rhohub* account. My *rhomobile* app requires *rhoconnect 3.2* with *ruby 1.9*. How to find which version of *ruby* is *rhohub* using?

I am trying to improve the response time by adding the following lines in my `config.ru` file.

```
# adjust the EventMachine Thread Pool size
require 'eventmachine'
EventMachine.threadpool_size = 25

# Rhoconnect server flags
Rhoconnect::Server.set     :use_async_model, true
# adjust the Rack FiberPool size
Rhoconnect::Server.set     :fiberpool_size, 150
```

Answer (score 0):

Command prompt and use  `ruby -v` will give you the current installed Ruby version.

Regards,
Amit C.